# scala how to write if else

Tags: scala

I am an new learner of scala, and i am trying to run this sample code

```
 def isLast(c: Int, r: Int):Int ={
   if(r == 1)
   {
   return 1;
   }

  else if (r == c){
   return 1
    }
   }
```

But it gives me compile time error, saying

```
Multiple markers at this line
- type mismatch;  found   : Unit  required: Int
- type mismatch;  found   : Unit  required: Int
```

Kindly help me, and also suggest me some good site for learning scala.

Comment: This is a good place to start Scala. http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, let's clean up your code a little:

```
def isLast(c: Int, r: Int):Int = {
  if(r == 1)
    return 1
  else if (r == c)
    return 1
  // but what about when r is neither 1 nor c ??
}
```

So you are telling scala that if `r` is 1, then return 1, and if `r == c`, return 1.  That's fine.  But if you want the method to return an Int, it has to return one in *every* case.  So Scala complains because it doesn't know what Int to return when `r` is neither 1 nor `c`.

The fix is to add an `else` clause than returns some other Int.

As an additional note, you can and should leave out the `return` keyword here, letting Scala implicitly know that the result of the if-else expression, as the last expression in the function's body, should be returned:

```
def isLast(c: Int, r: Int):Int = {
  if(r == 1)
    1
  else if (r == c)
    1
  else
    0 // or some other Int
}
```

As a final note, if you have a function whose name starts with `is`, then it should probably return a Boolean.  In other words, if the input *is last*, then return true, otherwise false.

Comment: Just as a note, idiomatically you should try to avoid using ``return``.

Answer (score 15):

I suspect you're trying to return `1` as a substitute for `true`. Don't; it is not.

Your logic is:

```
def isLast(c: Int, r: Int): Boolean = r == 1 || r == c
```

The `: Boolean` type annotation is optional. Here it's safe to leave it out because it's super-obvious what the return type is from the short expression on the right and your naming of the method. Don't use 10 lines of code when 1 will do.

Answer (score 3):

You have no "else" clause, just an "else if," so your function isn't guaranteed to return an integer.  If it falls through both conditions, you'll return nothing, which is a "Unit" return type.  You need to explicitly say `else 0`.

Comment: It's not Nothing, but if you don't explicitly return something, your return type is "Unit."

Answer (score 0):

Simply we can write If Else Statement:

```
scala> object TestIfElse{
def main(args: Array[String]){
var id = 10
if(id == 10)
println("Id is "+id)
else
println("Id is different")
}    }
```

Call Main Method Using:

```
scala>TestIfElse.main(Array())
```

Output is:

```
Id is 10
```